# MUI dependencies conflicts React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, dependencies

I`m trying to deploy React project with mui icons and components used.
While deploying on Vercel I get such errors:
[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsjsF.png)

Here's my package.lock:

```
{
  "name": "course",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "firebase": "^9.21.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-fade-in": "^2.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.11.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-textarea-autosize": "^8.4.1",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9"
  }, 
  
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.1.0"
  }
}
```

I've already tried running `npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps` and adding `"peerDependencies": { "react": "^18.1.0"}` to my package.lock file. It doesnt help.
What should I do better in this case?

Comment: Try to run after `npm cache clean --force` that `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`

Comment: You can also try to update your all package by `npm update`. Error indicates conflicts between different versions of React and Material-UI packages. So, it may fix your conflicts

Comment: it didn't help at all :(

Comment: Try deleting the package.lock file and the entire node_modules folder and reinstalling.

Comment: It is a very bad idea to install two versions of react with --legacy-peer-deps. Try downgrading react and react dom to v17 or upgrade @material-ui to v5 (now called @mui)

Answer (score 1):

Material UI v4 (`@material-ui/core`) does not work with React 18. Either upgrade Material UI to v5 (`@mui/material`) or use React 17.